# On continuity of $f^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $I$ be a non-empty real interval , then it is easy to prove that any injective continuous function $f:I\to \mathbb R$ is strictly monotone . Now let $A$ be a non-empty real set and $f:A\to \mathbb R$ be an injective continuous function , then is it true that $f$ is strictly monotone or atleast is it true that $f^{-1}:f(A) \to A$ is continuous ?

Comment: If $A$ is a finite set, you won't probably get any monotonicity...

Comment: When you say "continuous", it is for the induced topology on $A$? If so, I would gather not. Doesn't the function $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=(-1)^{x} x$ satisfy the conditions? (it is injective, continuous for the induced topology, but $f^{-1}(-1)=1$, $f^{-1}(0)=0$, $f^{-1}(2)=2$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity may fail if the domain is not an interval. To see this, take $D := (0,1) \cup [2,3)$ and

$$
f : D \to \Bbb{R}, x \mapsto \begin{cases}
x, & x\in\left(0,1\right)\\
x-1, & x\in\left[2,3\right).
\end{cases}
$$

Then $f$ is strictly increasing with $f\left(D\right)=\left(0,2\right)$,
but
$$
f^{-1}:\left(0,2\right)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},y\mapsto\begin{cases}
y, & y\in\left(0,1\right),\\
y+1, & y\in\left[1,2\right)
\end{cases}
$$
is not continuous at $y_{0}=1$.

In general, $f$ does not have to be strictly increasing, take e.g. $D = (-1,0) \cup (0,1)$ with

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x+1000, & x\in\left(-1,0\right)\\
x-1000, & x\in\left(0,1\right).
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: In your definition , $f(1/2)=1/2=f(5/2)$ , so how is $f$ injective ??

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I replaced "$x-2$" by "$x-1$". It should be correct now.